# Numpy random numbers - all in one go or call repeatedly?

Tags: python, random, numpy

I need to compute something like 10^8 uniformly distributed numbers in [0,1) for a Monte Carlo simulation. I can see two approaches to get these - compute all random numbers I need in one go, e.g. by using

```
numpy.random.random_sample(however_many_I_need)
```

or repeatedly call

```
numpy.random.random_sample()
```

Is there any difference in speed or quality of the random numbers between the two approaches?

Answer (score 5):

Why not time them and see?

```
import timeit
timeit.timeit("np.random.random_sample()", 
              setup="import numpy as np", 
              number=int(1E8))
```

14.27977508635054

```
timeit.timeit("np.random.random_sample(int(1E8))", 
              setup="import numpy as np", 
              number=1)
```

1.4685100695671025

As to the quality, both results will be as pseudo-random as the other - they come from the same generator. If you need something more secure it might be worth looking elsewhere, but if this is for a simple Monte Carlo problem I don't think you really need to.

PS [`timeit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) is great

Answer (score 2):

10^8 is a large number. As with all things numpy, this will be much faster if you pre-generate the numbers in one go, since you avoid the python function call overhead. This also applies for other operations you may want to do - additions, subtractions, multiplications, divisions, exponentiation, filtering, and lots of others

On the other hand, it doesn't help much if you pre-generate the numbers and the proceed to access each one individually from python. Make sure you can complete the simulation using matrix/vector operations.

As for the quality, there's no difference between the two methods you mention. If you need cryptographically secure random numbers, you should check @MayurPatel's answer. This is only needed if you need the random sequence to be **difficult to guess** for an attacker. For a monte carlo simulation you're probably more interested in statistical soundness, and numpy's `random` is enough

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using os.urandom()?  I believe this is the highest quality you will get natively in python; but it may not be as fast as some other methods.

Comment: A monte carlo simulation probably doesn't need cryptographically secure random numbers

Comment: FYI: `timeit.timeit("os.urandom(1)", setup="import os", number=int(1E8))` gives 135.40s; versus 0.44s from `timeit.timeit("os.urandom(int(1E8))", setup="import os", number=int(1))`.